# Can I .map() an array of 5 items if the array only has 3 items and append 2 placeholders?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I want to map an array of 5 items like so:

```
list.slice(0, 5).map((i) => {
    return <div>{i}</div>
});
```

However, If the array only has 3 items and I want to fill the remaining items in the array with placeholders in my react component. Can I do this with .map()? to display like so:

```
one
two
three
placeholder
placeholder
```

Comment: .map is for creating a new array based on an existing one, it will have the same number of items as the existing one. It is not for adding new items.

Comment: You mean that for any number of items from 0 to 4, the rest should be filled with a placeholder?

Comment: Might as well just loop 5 times, check whether or not there's an item to process, then act accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array.from()` to create an array of placeholder needed to fill the missing places in the list, and combine with the original list:

```js
const Demo = ({ list, minLength = 5 }) => (
  <ul>
  {[
    ...list,
    ...Array.from({ length: minLength - list.length }, () => 'placeholder')
    ].map((i) => <li>{i}</li>)
  }
  </ul>
);

const list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo list={list} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

You can also use `Array.from()` to render the items directly:

```js
const getLength = ({ length }, minLength) => minLength > length ? minLength : length;

const Demo = ({ list, minLength = 5 }) => (
  <ul>
  {Array.from({ ...list, length: getLength(list, minLength) }, o => 
    <li>{o === undefined ? 'placeholder' : o}</li>
  )}
  </ul>
);

const list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo list={list} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you're asking for with `map` alone. The other suggestions here are good, but in my opinion, it's a bit cleaner to use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) like this:

```
var list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var result = Array.from({length: 5}, (x, i) => i in list ? list[i] : 'placeholder');

console.log(result) // 'one', 'two', 'three', 'placeholder', 'placeholder'
```

This will produce an array of 5 elements regardless of whether `list` contains more or less than 5, so you can get rid of your call to `slice`. You'd use this in react like this:

```
Array.from({length: 5}, (x, i) => {
    return <div>{i in list ? list[i] : 'placeholder'}</div>
})
```

Answer (score 1):

No. As the `Array.prototype.map` docs mention, the function returns `a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.` Since list `list` only contains 3 elements, the `map` function will only iterate over those 3 elements.

However, if you wanted to add placeholders to the end of the array you could do something like (or a variety of other options):

```
const results = []
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  results.push(list[i] || 'placeholder')
}
```

For example, with the following list: `const list = ["a", "b", "c"]`, the output of the above code would be `["a", "b", "c", "placeholder", "placeholder"]`.

In the context of a React component you could map over `results`, and wrap each item in the array with a `div`, as you had originally intended.

Answer (score 0):

Not with `.map` alone, no - but, you could `push` to the `slice`ed array first, if its length is insufficient:

```
const sliced = list.slice(0, 5);
const { length } = sliced;
if (length < 5) {
  sliced.push(...new Array(5 - length).fill('placeholder'));
}
sliced.map(...
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot append additional elements to an array with `map()`. One solution is to first check the length of the input array and pad it with additional elements if necessary. Then `map()` as you are already.

Answer (score 0):

```
const list = [1, 2, 3];
list.slice(0, 5).concat(new Array(5 - list.length));
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A one liner (no warranty as to efficiency):

```
const list5 = list.map(...).concat([placeholder, placeholder, placeholder, placeholder, placeholder]).slice(0,5);
```

If you are doing this a bunch of times the placeholder[] could be a constant.